# How do I display text being pulled from the dictionary api?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I have made it have a dictionary in a dictionary, but cannot display the information. I have tried using a string variable but it does not work for  me.

I tried to make it show text or stats from the dictionary I am using. I have been told to use a textbox to display, but I don't know how to incorporate it into my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import http.client as SuperheroDictionary
from ast import literal_eval

# Variables
Powerstats = {}
Biography = {}
Work = {}
Images = {}

#Database connections
conn = SuperheroDictionary.HTTPSConnection("superhero-search.p.rapidapi.com")
headers = {
 'X-RapidAPI-Key': "15cf40731cmsh0b0d641628dcaa8p1231a2jsnc91f57193d96",
 'X-RapidAPI-Host': "superhero-search.p.rapidapi.com"}

# Functions
def search():
 conn.request("GET", f"/api/?hero={SearchBar.get()}", headers=headers)
 res = conn.getresponse()
 data = res.read()
 results = literal_eval(data.decode("utf-8"))

 Powerstats = results['powerstats']
 print(Powerstats)
 Appearance = results['appearance']
 print(Appearance)
 Biography = results['biography']
 print(Biography)
 Work = results['work']
 print(Work)
 Images = results['images']
 print(Images)
 return Powerstats, Appearance, Biography, Work, Images

def display():
 x_var.set(list(results))

# Create Window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")
window.title("Superheroes")

# Widgets
MainTitle = tk.Label(window, text="Superhero's Dictionary!", font=('Ariel', 40))
MainTitle.place(x=50, y=50)
SearchBar = tk.Entry(window, width=20)
SearchBar.place(x=60, y=125)
SearchButton = tk.Button(window, text="Search", command=search, bd= 4,)
SearchButton.place(x=200, y=125)
button2 = tk.Button(window, text="Display", command=display).place(x= 290, y= 125)
intelligence = tk.Label(window, text="Stats: ")
intelligence.place(x=60, y=200)
C = tk.Canvas(window, height=300, width=400, bd=3)
C.place(x=550, y=600)
x_var = StringVar()
tk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=x_var).place(x=60, y=210)
intelligence1 = tk.Label(window, text=f"Stats: {Powerstats} ")
intelligence1.place(x=60, y=220)
intelligence2 = tk.Label(window, text=f"Stats: {Appearance}")
intelligence2.place(x=60, y=240)
intelligence3 = tk.Label(window, text=f"Stats: {Biography}")
intelligence3.place(x=60, y=260)
intelligence4 = tk.Label(window, text=f"Stats: {Work}")
intelligence4.place(x=60, y=280)
intelligence5 = tk.Label(window, text=f"Stats: {Images}")
intelligence5.place(x=60, y=300)



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You already know how to display text using labels, so what is the difficulty on showing the content of the dictionary?

Comment: I don't see `mainframe` declared anywhere.